# RuntimeError when using Ubuntu dataset in Chatterbot

Tags: python, ubuntu, dataset, runtime-error, chatterbot

I run this code which I found over at the [chatterbot training examples on Github](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/examples/training_example_ubuntu_corpus.py) and it all went well. It downloaded and extracted the file correctly as everything should be. Then I run my code and the file kinda froze.

This is the code:

```
import logging
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import UbuntuCorpusTrainer

# Enable info level logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

chatbot = ChatBot('Example Bot')

trainer = UbuntuCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

# Start by training our bot with the Ubuntu corpus data
trainer.train()

# Now let's get a response to a greeting
response = chatbot.get_response('How are you doing today?')
print(response)
```

And here is the error I get:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:File is already downloaded
INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:File is already extracted
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:File is already downloaded
INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:File is already extracted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Coding\PyProjects\Sociality\Sociality3\Test\test2\tester.py", line 13, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\benbe\.virtualenvs\benbe-ZCclz55H\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\trainers.py", line 342, in train
    manager = Manager()
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 56, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 513, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 33, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\benbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Note that the code keeps running without crashing but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: it seems it uses `multiprocessing` - and on Windows when you use `multiprocessing` then you have to run code in `if __name__ == '__main__':` - this way other processes will not run again all code from the beginning. And you have some information about `if __name__ == '__main__':` in error message.